# What are the principle/fundamental differences between Sunni and Shia?

Tags: quran, sunni, shiism, shia-sunni, sects

Although I do believe that the separation into sects of Islam is terrible and contradicts with the Qur'an (6:159, 30:32 and etc...) I'm interested in knowing why there is so much conflict between both sects and the major religious difference. I would personally call myself a Muslim rather than label myself as Sunni/Shia/Suffi etc...

Please no biased answers (unless you state it is your opinion :p).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Please no biased answers (unless you state it is your opinion :p).

I don't understand how are you not going to get biased answers in this matter.

Everyone loves to call he is just Muslim, and if you ask him how is that, he says, it is possible by being a Sunni Muslim. If you ask the same question to someone else, he would say, Shias are the only true Muslims out there. Suffis consider all others don't know anything about Islam except them.

This thing is solely opinion based.

As for this...

> What are the principle/fundamental differences between Sunni and Shia?

That's a way too broad question. But as far as I've seen...

> In the Sunni branch of Islam, the canonical hadith collections are the six books, of which Sahih al-Bukhari and Sahih Muslim generally have the highest status. The other books are Sunan Abu Dawood, Jami` at-Tirmidhi, Al-Sunan al-Sughra and Sunan ibn Majah. However the Malikis, one of the five Sunni "schools of thought" (madhhabs), traditionally reject Sunan ibn Majah and assert the canonical status of Muwatta Imam Malik.
>
> In the Shi'a branch of Islam, the canonical hadith collections are the Four Books: Kitab al-Kafi, Man la yahduruhu al-Faqih, Tahdhib al-Ahkam, and Al-Istibsar. ([Hadith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith))

There lies the main difference I can say. The Hadith which Sunnis consider to be authentic (directly from the mouth of Prophet Muhammad(pbuh)) are not considered to be authentic by Shias and vice versa. This can be the main root to today's disparities between Shia and Sunni beliefs. But back then, you know, **it is politics**.

> why there is so much conflict between both sects and the major religious difference?

Ego and Shaitan

> I would personally call myself a Muslim rather than label myself as Sunni/Shia/Suffi etc...

Yeah even me too.

May the creator guide us all.

---

Note: This answer is not to hurt any sect/madhab, and opinions stated above are just randomly formulated.

Comment: I think just calling one's self a muslim, is an easy and actually lazy way of avoiding some significant questions about true essence of Islam. One can not claim to be a muslim but have a neutral position on these important differences. Neutral position can also be an indication that one is still indecisive and in the process of learning about these differences until he or she can make conclusions and decide which sect is closer to original Islam. I think you are in the latter group that are commendable for their quest for truth.

Comment: Yeah you can say that, but you're missing one point, we have the freedom to pick a few things from one group, and discard the ones we don't like from it, then move to next and repeat the the process. Howz that? @infatuated

Comment: Good, but try to be as open and at same time as critical as possible. Study in depth and be open to all possibilities. Look for more coherency with Quran and reason. Also look at the historical record set by different sects in terms of their social/political/intellectual achievements and contributions (or their losses and harms).

Comment: @servantofWiser, I almost agree your response as a suitable answer. Actually perhaps presenting or quoting the authentic and unauthentic sources of hadiths made the main differences ...